# how can I calculate all valid numbers from a binary representation of a decimal number? like 1011 to 1110 this is also a valid number

Tags: c++, theory

Examples are

A B C

1 2 3

369 428 797

We can consider A=01 and B=10 in binary. Then, there are two possible ways: swapping the two bits of A and the two bits of B (As=10, Bs=01 in binary, 2 and 1 in decimal representation) or not shuffling any bits.

number 2 is done in same way but dont know how to do it.... in c++ code
is there any basic idea I am missing

I can use the code to find all combinations of string to solve this...
but this will take too much time for 10^9
time limit is 1s

this code shows all combinations of string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
 This function takes three parameters:
 1. String
 2. Starting index of the string
 3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
  int i;
  if (l == r)
    printf("%s\n", a);
  else
  {
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
      swap((a+l), (a+i));
      permute(a, l+1, r);
      swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
    }
  }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
  char str[] = "10000000000111111110101010101010101";
  int n = strlen(str);
  permute(str, 0, n-1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is a complete legal C program - nothing special of C++ is used. Even the includes are C standard library headers. Are you sure you took the right language tag?

Comment: Do you actually want to calculate all valid numbers? Or you just need the number of valid numbers? Because the former is really not possible in the time you mentioned. Try to be more clearer with the question I think?